# Draining water in the house

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

I have a two story house plus a basement.  It's an older house and the water pressure isn't that great.  I've seen a little crud on one of the screens on a sprinkler timer that's hooked up to a spigot on the main floor.  Since I have an outside spigot on the basement.  I was thinking about turning off the water to the house and draining the water in the house out the basement spigot.  I was hoping this might flush out some sediment and stuff.  I'm thinking it might be a good idea to turn off the power to the water heater while I do this. Is there anything else I should worry about? Obviously there will be a bunch of air in the lines, but i don't think that bleeding it will be a problem.

Comment: Turning off power to water heater is very good idea.   To drain water need to close main valve, open lowest tap/faucet/spigot. and open top/highest faucet to let air in.  Some sediment might come out.  Would check screens in the faucets first to see if they are block.  City or well water?

Comment: There could be some sediment or calcification impeding flow but that may not be the problem. Are you on a well or city water? If it's a city hookup do you have a pressure regulating valve (PRV). Have you measured the actual pressure that you're getting? Your water dept should be able to tell you what the curb pressure is coming into your house. That will tell you what you kind of pressure you're working with.

Comment: I'd be careful, depending upon the type of plumbing. If galvanized steel pipes (likely in an older home), you could have a ton of rust buildup inside the pipes. Draining it, then refilling with a lot of air pockets could bust a lot of that loose and make things a lot worse.   As steel pipes rust, they expand inward, shrinking the interior size of the pipes, which leads to lower and lower water pressure.   There may be other causes like @HoneyDo said, but be careful here.

Comment: We are on city water.  In the spots where I can see pipes running under the flooer, they all appear to be PCV, but it's hard to know what's inside the walls.  The house was built in 1978.